# Wrong customer group id returned in subtotal.phtml?

Tags: magento, session

I am using

```
$id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
```

in *app\design\frontend\base\default\template\tax\checkout\subtotal.phtml* to get the customers group id. It always returns 1, which is not correct. At other template files, it returns the correct number in the **same** session.

I am logged in as the correct customer, this cant be the problem.

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to get the Role or group id ? the above code returns the group id of specific role.what is the group id of your group on admin side ?

Answer (score 0):

Today i stumbled upon the same problem so i thought i'd share my findings on this one.

In our store the *Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group* (Config -> System -> Customer Configuration -> Create New Account Options) setting was enabled. Whenever a customer was logged in i got different results for the customer's group id depending on where the block requesting this information was placed in the layout. I then found out that it's the Minicart-Block messing up things.

If the *automatic customer group assignmen*t setting is enabled magento will execute an Observer from `Mage_Sales`: `Mage_Sales_Model_Observer::changeQuoteCustomerGroupId`. This is due to the minicart collecting totals on the Quote.

This observer takes the address from the quote and validates whether there is a VAT ID present for that address and if not whether the chosen country is part of the European Union.

If not, it will **assign the default usergroup** to the quote - but moreover it also will assign that usergroup to the **user object**, this is where things get messy:

```
if ((empty($customerVatNumber) || !Mage::helper('core')->isCountryInEU($customerCountryCode))
        && !$isDisableAutoGroupChange
    ) {
        $groupId = ($customerInstance->getId()) ? $customerHelper->getDefaultCustomerGroupId($storeId)
            : Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID;

        $quoteAddress->setPrevQuoteCustomerGroupId($quoteInstance->getCustomerGroupId());
        $customerInstance->setGroupId($groupId);
        $quoteInstance->setCustomerGroupId($groupId);

        return;
    }
```

The problem is that there will **never** be a VAT ID or country set on the quote address when you add a product to an empty cart. These values will only be filled out during checkout process and can't be entered before. That means that for every customer that has a cart but hasn't been to checkout process yet Magento will assign the *default user group* to the user.

I ended up disabling the original observer and checking if there is any value for the `country_id` attribute set on the quote address.

If it's not set i get the `vat_id` and `country_id` values from the default addresses, if any, set them on the quote address and then defer to the original observer.

```
public function changeQuoteCustomerGroupId(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var $quoteAddress Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address */
    $quoteAddress = $observer->getQuoteAddress();
    $quoteInstance = $quoteAddress->getQuote();
    $customerInstance = $quoteInstance->getCustomer();

    if (!$quoteAddress->getCountryId())
    {
        // no country chosen, yet. Copy default billing addresses value to quote address.

        $primaryBillingAddress = $customerInstance->getPrimaryAddress('default_' . $quoteAddress->getAddressType());

        if ($primaryBillingAddress->getId())
        {
            $quoteAddress->setVatId($primaryBillingAddress->getVatId());
            $quoteAddress->setCountryId($primaryBillingAddress->getCountryId());

        }
    }

    Mage::getSingleton('sales/observer')->changeQuoteCustomerGroupId($observer);

    return $this;
}
```

`config.xml`

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before>
        <observers>
            <sales_customer_validate_vat_number>
                <type>disabled</type>
            </sales_customer_validate_vat_number>
            <fallback_customer_validate_vat_number>
                <class>vendor/sales_observer</class>
                <method>changeQuoteCustomerGroupId</method>
            </fallback_customer_validate_vat_number>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before>
<events>
```

Maybe this will be helpful for someone.